# Navbar link's padding area not clickable

Tags: html, css

I created a navbar and I can't figure out how to get the padding areas of the link to be clickable just like the link.

I have the padding configured in this part of my CSS..

```
.spectator_nav li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 25px 20px;
}
```

I created a fiddle. Mine doesn't look like this, but it is enough to show the hover effect and how the padding areas of the link are not clickable to go to the link.

How can I make the padding areas clickable to go to the link?

https://jsfiddle.net/mykx37n9/

Comment: Put the padding on the link...not the `li`. Simple really,

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I over looked that. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, you're padding out the <li> and not the <a>. With the <a> being the 'clickable' element it's this that needs the padding. The <li> will grow to the size of the <a> so long as there's nothing overriding (a more specific style).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add the padding to the link within the `<li>`

**try:**

```
.spectator_nav li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.spectator_nav li a{
    padding: 25px 20px;
}
```